# Accento in parole composte

Tags: pronunciation

Mi chiedo quali siano le regole di accentazione delle parole composte, se ne esistono.

È noto che [la maggior parte delle parole italiane sono piane](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accentazione-piana_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/). Quello che vorrei scoprire è se esistono regole, o tendenze comuni, nell'accentazione di parole composte.

Alcuni esempi (inventati da me; apprezzo riscontro su eventuali errori):

- Camposanto (piana) = campo (piana) + santo (piana)
- Lavastoviglie (piana) = lava (piana) + stoviglie (piana)
- Saltimbanco (piana) = salta (piana) + in (tronca) + banco (piana)

Si può parlare di una regola, per esempio, dove la parola composta prende l'accento tonico dall'ultimo componente? Ci sono esempi che contraddirebbero questa regola?

##### Altri riferimenti

https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composizione_(linguistica)

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: Le preposizioni semplici sono proclitiche, non prendono mai accento; quindi “in banco” si pronuncia come se fosse “\*imbànco” (o “\*inbànco” nelle varietà di italiano dove “nb” non è un problema).

Comment: In italiano hanno due o più accenti tutte le parole composte: "accèndisìgari", "àlfabèto", "àutoblìndomitragliatrìce", "buònaséra", "fìdejussióne", "pómodòro", "sàliscéndi", e via discorrendo. https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accento_secondario

Answer (score 2):

Nel caso di parole composte, occorre distinguere tra **accento primario** e **accento secondario**. In genere, l'accento primario è quello del secondo componente, mentre l'accento secondario è quello del primo. L'accento primario delle parole composte è dunque generalmente quello del loro ultimo componente.

Estratto da [Enciclopedia dell'Italiano](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accento-fonico-prontuario_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/) (in *6. Doppia accentazione*):

> Le parole di almeno tre sillabe possono avere uno o più accenti secondari, di minore intensità rispetto a quello primario. Il fenomeno è particolarmente evidente nelle parole composte, in cui l’accento del primo componente coincide con l’accento secondario mentre l’accento del secondo componente coincide con l’accento primario: càssa + pànca dà cassapanca [ˌkasːaˈpaŋka], parola piana con accento secondario sulla prima sillaba cas.

**Ci sono esempi che contraddirebbero questa regola?**

Due eccezioni che mi vengono in mente sono (entrambe dal greco):

- Antìpodi
- Antìtipo

Comment: Grazie. Quindi, per completare la risposta in modo esplicito, si può dire che la regola è: le parole composte acquisiscono l'accento primario – quello che determina se una parola è piana, tronca, eccetera – _dall'ultima componente_? Se aggiungi una nota a riguardo nel corpo della tua risposta sarò felice di accettarla.

Comment: Giuseppe, se parliamo di parole composte in generale (quindi formate indifferentemente da nomi, aggettivi, verbi, prefissi etc.) le eccezioni sono innumerevoli: molte, come dici giustamente, dal greco (omologo, esagono, bibliofilo, monotono etc.). Penso che quel passo dell'Enciclopedia dell'italiano si riferisca ai casi nome+nome (cassapanca) e al massimo anche verbo+nome (tagliaborse).

Comment: @DaG e Giuseppe: non sono sicuro che considererei parole come "omologo", "antipodi" etc. come parole composte. Piuttosto sono parole costruite con prefissi o suffissi che erano parole indipendenti in greco o latino, ma non lo sono più in italiano.

Comment: @DenisNardin La parola "antipodi" è citata in ["La grammatica italiana"](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/anti_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/) fra gli esempi di parole composte contenenti il prefisso "anti-".